# django: sum and group at the same time?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have a model where I have a quantity, a price and a currency field:

```
quantity   price   currency
1          5       USD
2          3       USD
1          7       EUR
```

I would like to sum the total price per currency.
Basically, manually here is the result:

```
USD: 1*5  + 2*3 = 11
EUR: 1*7 = 7
```

I have tried several things with annotate and Sum but could not make it work. :/

Should I just use plain SQL to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I finally found the solution:

```
items.values('currency').annotate(total=Sum('price', field='price*quantity'))
```